# When did Londoners stop using yus for yes? Or did they?

Tags: word-usage

I grew up in London in the 50s and the kids on my street used yus for yes.

Comment: Why do you use 'on'? 'On my street' instead of 'in my street'.

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy because the kids in the street stopped using yus when they were buried there.

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy  FWIW I would also say 'on my street' in Leeds, Yorkshire. That's just the way it is :)

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy In my opinion because **_in_ the street** refers only to people who are standing or passing by there (I stood at my window and watched the people walking in the street) but **_on_ the street**, although it can be used for traffic and passers by, is more usually used for the local inhabitants (The men on my street all worked at the local colliery). **_In_ the street** never refers to the local inhabitants in that way.

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy As far as I've always said (and as far as those I've interacted with have always said), *kids live (in houses) **on** a street.* Kids never live ***in*** a street. (If they did, they'd be hit by passing cars.) They might *play* ***in*** a street—but, again, they'd have to be careful of passing cars.

Comment: Thanks to all! I see. Nice joke, candied_orange. :) But I'm also curious how people would answer Stefany's question.